# GitHub API returning 404 although resource exists

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to send a POST request to the GitHub API to submit a comment on a commit.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-comment), all that's needed (other than the URL params) is the `body`.

I have modified the example from the docs to the following:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/dchacke/test/commits/9b7413350932dd3f2906c0fdd26106c35c7ce450/comments \
  -d '{"body":"test comment"}'
```

That *should* post a test comment to [this commit](https://github.com/dchacke/test/commit/9b7413350932dd3f2906c0fdd26106c35c7ce450). I know the commit and the owner and repo exist (it's my repo and I can see the commit under that URL), and yet I'm getting a 404 with the following response body upon submitting that API request:

```json
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-comment"
}
```

The documentation makes no mention of authentication being required for that endpoint. A 404 doesn't exactly sound like an authentication problem, but just in case GitHub [doesn't want to confirm the existence of repos/commits to unauthenticated users](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication) (though they *do* let them see those things on their website...), I tried setting a personal access token in an additional `Authorization` header in my CURL request. No dice.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authentication *was* the issue after all. I had to make sure I used a token with the right privileges. In this case, it needed the `public_repo` privilege, which can be set up [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new).

Comment: Minor clarification here: the repo mentioned is a public repo, so adding public_repo is the fix in this case. If you're trying to use the API against a non-public repo, the only way (with a 'classic' PAT) is to give it `repo` (aka permission. Even checking all the boxes immediately under `repo` won't work.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple Yeah, that is all correct. I keep running into this. It's so frustrating :)